# How do I get sender's UDP port in C?

Tags: c, udp

I have the following typical code in C under Linux to get UDP data:

```
sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
mysock.sin_family = AF_INET;
mysock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
mysock.sin_port = my_port;
bind(sock, &mysock, sizeof(mysock);
recvfrom(sock, buf, PKTSZ, 0, &client, len);
```

All the above code works, but now I have a need to find out the sender's udp port, is there a structure or system call I can use to retrieve such info when I receive a udp packet ?

thanks

Answer (score 18):

> recvfrom(sock, buf, PKTSZ, 0, &client, len);

The senders socket address is stored in the **client** variable of your code. To access the senders port use **sockaddr_in** instead of **sockaddr**. Example:

```
sockaddr_in client;
int len = sizeof(client);
recvfrom(sock, buf, PKTSZ, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t *)&len);
int port = ntohs(client.sin_port);
```

References:
[Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html#sendtorecv) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: reinterpret_cast does not belong here.  The OP asked for C (not C++)

Answer (score 6):

recvfrom() is supposed to return that to you in the fifth argument (struct sockaddr*).

**EDIT:** 
Use something like this

```
struct sockaddr_in client;

recvfrom(... (struct sockaddr*)&client ...);
```

`client.sin_port` should be the sender's port.

Comment: I look at that argument before but the struct sockaddr does not have any sender's udp port info, unless it is embedded inside the sa_data.

Answer (score 1):

UDP sender port would be transient. I don't think you could use that for anything other than for reporting.

Comment: I might not make myself clear, I need to know the sender's udp port so I can send data back immediately, so it's ok to be transient.

Comment: you can only send data back to a listening udp socket. It's unlikely that your sender socket is also a listening socket. If you need this behaviour, you need to have listening udp sockets on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

The fifth argument can be cast to `struct sockaddr_in`, and there `sin_port` is the remote port number.

Answer (score 0):

Casting the client to sockaddr_in solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Remember the ntohs() above all!  It wasn't until I used the programmer's calculator that I realized it WAS stored as BigEndian 15B3, not the presumably ephemeral port B315!